# Add dynamic value inside brackets of value

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, repeat

Can I add dynamic value with repeat inside the two `{}` brackets of value, example below will explain clearly

```
<apex:repeat value="{!fieldsAPINamesList}" var="fieldName">
    <!-- I NEED THIS {!fieldName} VALUE TO BE REPLACED WITH fieldName BELOW IN LABEL -->
    <apex:inputField label="{!$ObjectType.customObj__c.fields.fieldName.InlineHelpText}"
                     value="{!objRecord[fieldName]}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to the value that is in the `label` attribute on the `inputField` you can do this with array syntax the same way you're doing it with the `value` attribute.

```
label="{!$ObjectType.customObj__c.fields[fieldName].InlineHelpText}"
```

SFDC Reference Doc: [Dynamic References to Schema Details Using $ObjectType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_globals_objecttype.htm)